# Passing state information from view to viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

What is the best approach to pass the current view model state - specifically what textbox has focus - back to the view model?

My requirement is for context specific search, depending what text box has focus determines what field to search on in the database.

I'm using the MVVM pattern and really don't want to put any code in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `InvokeCommandAction` available in the Expression Blend SDK:

```
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBox>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="GotFocus">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Where:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

Comment: should just add that you need the System.Windows.Interactivity.dll added as a reference, which can be found in the Silverlight 4 SDK

Answer (score 2):

create an attached property for the `TextBox` which is an `IsFocussed` property. Then use 2 way binding to your `ViewModel`

Comment: can this be extended so instead of relying on IsFocused and property setters my attached property would return the type of search to perform specified by an enum?

Comment: Yes, set the enum on a second attached property, and then use the value of that attached property in evaluating the first attached property

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to put view related stuff in your VM. Focus is clearly view related stuff. In the VM you should keep track of the currently selected search field in some bindable property. Changing focus in the view should update the current property somehow. I don't see a problem with code behind in the view, which would be the easiest way of keeping track of focus and updating the VM. If you don't want to do code behind, then this can also be done by value converters or attached behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see a way of doing this without slightly violating the View-ViewModel contract (ie. the ViewModel is View agnostic). You can use `System.Windows.Input`'s `Keyboard.FocusedElement` and then get that element's data binding to perform your search within your search command in your ViewModel.